# Get the data by one from psql database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

On my Postgres database I have two tables the dates and the stocks (tickers). i need for a specific period of time (`2014-1-1 to 2015-1-1`) in each day d on that period i need to go back 10 days and go forward 10 days and get the list of stocks that contains from `d-10` to `d+10`.
the result should be as follow for each day `[(d1:s1,s2,...),(d2:,s1,s2,...),...]`
I tried to get all data first then select my needed but it take a lot of time.

```
data=SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2015-1-1'
```

then i get the stocks.
Any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data from your table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE date BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20150101'
```

or

```
   SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE date >'20140101' AND date <'20150101'
```